# How would I exaggerate (elongate) the amount of time it takes to download a file using javascript

Tags: javascript, time, download

I am working a netart project and am interested in creating a site where files would literally take years to download. Is this possible and if so how would i go about doing so ? Would .js be the correct lanquage when handling this task?

Comment: JS is designed to create interactive website content, I can't begin to imagine how you would use it to control bandwidth.

Comment: well couldn't i control the time it take a file to upload the same way i can control an animation? an or a pop-up?

Comment: obviously its different but it is still just a time issue

Answer (score 0):

*Well that is quite strange you know :) but, yes you might use .js for this task.*

**Framework Setup :**

1. MongoDB - database
2. Node.js - server ( handling calls, db calls, etc.)
3. Express.js - for very fast and easy server creation
4. Angular.js - client side app logic

If you are fluent with .js you should have finish creating, site with filedownload functionality in about two hours.

***1.*** On the server side you will  use express.js somehow like this:

```
        app.get('/test', function(req, res){
            res.write(fileChunk);
                // SetTimeOut function to delay sending of the next chunk
            res.write(fileChunk);
        });
```

The interesting question is what happens when the computer downloading the file have setTimeOut function for receiving  responses. But `connection: keep-alive` is most likely used parameter for connections so it should work.

***2.*** You can also manipulate the download bandwidth limit of server that is sending the file.